# Laravel. Migrations. Adding a field

Tags: laravel, sqlite, laravel-5

I insert the field like this:

```
$table->timestamp('added_on')->default('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
```

but in SQLite the default value is 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' and it does not work (does not replace with the current date). It is necessary that the field had the value CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, then it will work. Can this be done in Laravel?

Comment: Why not use $table->timestamps()? then you will have 2 fields: created_at and updated_at that laravel will handle automatically. And then if you absolutely want the field to be named added_on add an accesor.

Comment: thanks, next time i will use this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping it in `DB::raw` so it's executed as a SQL function:

```
$table->timestamp('added_on')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
```

Or you can use `->useCurrent();` Laravel helper like this :

```
$table->timestamp('added_on')->useCurrent();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it

Comment: Using useCurrent() solved the problem. You helped me a lot - I choose your answer as the best